# Move Tab Bar to top of screen

Tags: ios, iphone, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab Bar Controller which, as we know, displays the tab bar at the bottom of the screen.  I'm looking for a way to move it to the top.  I don't think I can use a simple `UITabBar` for this as I need to nest `UINavigationControllers` under it.

Is there any way to move the Tab Bar in a `UITabBarController` to the top of the screen?

Answer (score 9):

Try this code in methods "viewDidLayoutSubviews"  your **UITabBarController**

**Swift 2.X**

```
  self.tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,50) //example for iPhone 5
```

**Swift 3.X**

```
  self.tabBar.frame = CGRect(0,0,320,50) //example for iPhone 5
```

**Swift 4.X**

```
  self.tabBar.frame = CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)  //example for iPhone 5
```

Comment: I do the same but it's not working in my case. I just want to remove tabbar in some screens but it's not working.

Comment: Do code in methods "viewDidLayoutSubviews" of Tabbar class

Comment: Ohh it's working but please mention in your answer. Thank You once again.

Answer (score 4):

(in Swift)

In the TabBarViewController.swift file (everyone has named this file as he wants):

- First: create an IBOutlet of a tab bar and then connect it to the appropiate tab bar in the storyboard or in the nib file.

  ```
  @IBOutlet var profileTabBar : UITabBar!
  ```
- Second: add this code in the **viewDidLoad()** function to situate the tab bar where you want (in this case I add de tab bar under the navigation controller). To modify the position change **x** and **y** of **CGRectMake** initializer.

  ```
  // [Maybe you don't have a navigation controller] yNavBar indicates the height of the navigation bar. 
  var yNavBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
  // yStatusBar indicates the height of the status bar 
  var yStatusBar = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
  // Set the size and the position in the screen of the tab bar
  profileTabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, yNavBar! + yStatusBar + profileTabBar.frame.size.height, profileTabBar.frame.size.width, profileTabBar.frame.size.height)
  ```

Comment: Is the TabBarViewController a subclass of UITabBarController?

Comment: No, the TabBarViewController class doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked for me but I am having a black region at the place from where I moved the tabbar. Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. The only thing I can think of is to use UITabBar instead of UITabbarController ...

This might be a better option anyway if you are considering nesting UINavigationControllers for each view loaded for the different tabs.

Comment: please tell me how to set uitabbar in left side of view. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

in the viewDidLayoutSubviews() put this code like this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,height: 30)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I use `Tab Bar Controller` then I simply change the `TabBar` position in the `Tab Bar Controller` in the `ViewDidLoad()`

```
import UIKit

class TabbarViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBar.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :64), size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 50))

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Here is the Screen Short attached of the required result...
[Tab bar on top in tab bar view conmtroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUZmO.png)

Note: **It is in swift 3** you can change the syntax to swift 2.* on your own.

Comment: this doesn't work. You can't put this on viewDidLoad func