# Monotouch combine TabBar and Toolbar

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, uisplitviewcontroller, toolbar

Hy community,
I have a question: I want to have a toolbar which is at the top of all three tabviews.
If I add the toolbar in the interface builder to the splitviewcontroller, the toolbar isn't showed. Here is a screenshot of my ui:

http://www.abload.de/img/bildschirmfoto2012-12ato6r.png

Thanks

Comment: Are you dragging/dropping a toolbar on there? What autoresizing options are set for it? (should be docked to the top and able to resize its width) Or are you merely setting a  property on the controller? (there are a few properties that let you see what certain situations "would" look like)

Comment: Thanks, I did it by faking the SplitController

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried a lot of different things and didnt find a solution. Even if you move the tab bar 1 pixel up and not binding it to the bottom of the screen, it wont show. No difference if its added in xcode or programmatically. I think it has something to do with Apple's design principles?

Found this btw: [Move Tab Bar to top of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684425/move-tab-bar-to-top-of-screen)

So i ended up programming a SegmentedControl instead.