# Tab Bar Similar to Words With Friends

Tags: ios, swift

I really like the UI Layout of apps like WordsWithFriends and in particular, I'm trying to emulate their TabBar on top.

[(Sorry, new user and can't put pics directly in the body)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKOOn.png)

[Second pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG3WT.png)

I know the AppStore recommends against tab bars on top, but I was hoping someone here might know how these guys get away with it. Is it not even a tab bar at all and in fact something else? I'd just rather leave the bottom part of the screen open for other functionality if I can - is there a way to put the tab bar up top, maybe programmatically? If a tab bar isn't the best way to do it though, I'm open to more suggestions.

(edited for clarification)

Comment: You are asking how the referenced app was approved by Apple. That's not exactly a programming question.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to know how the app was approved or how it was implemented?

Comment: Ok sorry, I guess what I really want to know is how to make it in xcode because the default uitabbar doesn't allow me to put it on top, but I know its possible

Comment: It's clearly a custom control. Write your own or search for an existing 3rd party one.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684425/move-tab-bar-to-top-of-screen

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use a UITabBarController just to use a tab bar. A tab bar is its own independent entity which you can use in your own view controller and thus place anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you as i get what you're asking for. Basically its not a tab bar but yeah it's cool to get that behavior with paging and swiping.[This is what you are looking for basically](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu)

[image: These images show the *tab bar* you're looking for]

Hope it helps!